# Is Copying for List Assignments acceptable?

Tags: python, copy, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

Consider the following minimal example:

```py
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, length):
        self._list = [[] for _ in range(length)]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._list[key] = value.copy()
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._list[key]
```

Now, the Python documentation says:

> *Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object.*

Applying the class above would mean something like:

```py
>>> l = [[1,2,3,4], [3,2,1,0]]
>>> C = MyClass(2)
>>> C[0] = l[0]
```

This is indeed an assignment statement. But the values are copies now:

```py
>>> C[0] == l[0]
True
>>> C[0] is l[0]
False
```

Is that an acceptable behavior for a class in Python?

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: That's quite difficult to explain. I am involved in the SageMath project and we are dealing with mutable element, i.e. tensors.

Comment: I need a class that saves tensors in a list. But this is a whole new mutable element. The connection to the original tensors might become somehow invisible. The question is whether a list assignment via copying is a wanted behavior then.

Comment: Furthermore, we want to add a method which makes this element immutable. Making the tensors immutable along the way might be undesirable for the user.

Comment: Classes can do whatever makes sense for them. The documentation is just describing the default behavior.

Comment: It is acceptable, just surprising behavior.

Comment: Deviations from the default behavior might confuse the user. So you say, it is acceptable, however, if avoidable it should be avoided?

Comment: This isn't "list assignment" because this isn't a list. This is just you implementing your own item-assignment semantics. There is nothing inherently wrong with this. Note, this isn' really variable assignment either.

Comment: @juanpa: Could you point out the difference please? This might be a crucial point for me to understand this properly.

Comment: variable assignment is `x = whatever`, i.e., the left hand side is a *variable*. When you do `something[item] = value` that's something else, you can think of it as syntactic sugar for `something.__setitem__(self, item, value)` so it's some method of whatever container class you are using.

Comment: This makes perfect sense and is easier as I first thought. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with this. As long as your class is well documented, if you have a good reason to do this go for it. Consider the following class from the standard library `shelve` module, which essentially provides a dict-like database interface. Since using `object[key] = value` will write to disk, and retrieving that object will retrieve it from disk, it won't give you the same object (necessarily, there are caching options)! So:

```
In [1]: import shelve

In [2]: data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

In [3]: database = shelve.open('db')

In [4]: database['key'] = data[0]

In [5]: database['key']
Out[5]: [1, 2, 3]

In [6]: database['key'] is data[0]
Out[6]: False
```

That part of the documentation is referring to assignment statements to a variable, like this:

```
some_var = foo
```

Where indeed, it *never* copies. And you can't really change that (well, maybe, but that's another question). You are free to implement `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` however you wish.

Comment: @YoungMath heh, yeah, usually, "is this acceptable" is a borderline opinion-based question, but I think "well, the standard library does it" is as close to an objective "it's OK" as there is.